# mailto not working with android jellybean

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, mailto

I’m working on a mobile site using JQM and I’m having trouble setting the body text for Android version 4 and up. The address and subject work.

This is the code.

```
var shareEmail = "mailto:"+thisAddress+"?&subject=" + encodeURIComponent(+thisSubject) + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(thisBody);
```

It works fine in earlier versions.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this, works fine for me :)

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("message/rfc822");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"EMAIL ADRESS"});
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SUBJECT");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "BODY");
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send email..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(Start.this, "Sorry, there is no email client installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Cheers, Felix